# how to show visualforce template in different languages

Tags: email-template

i have tried the translation workbench where i need to translate the visualforce email template content where email body placed in custom label.created a new picklist field in Account Object where iam setting the language Keys and i enabled the translation workbench. when I try to test template showing in the English language

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="erorr" relatedToType="Account" language="{!relatedTo.PreferedLanguages__c}">
    <messaging:htmlEmailBody >
        {!$Label.WorkbenchData}
    </messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Comment: what is the specific question?

Comment: wether i need to translate text in custom label first ??